# Upload control in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have created the file upload control in GWT and have one submit button whose click starts my upload.

Now I want to start the upload the moment the user selects the file,and want to submit the form there,this will reduce one extra submit button from my form.

Please tell me the way and the event that is fired when the user selects the file and how I can achieve that using GWT.

Thanks

Aman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add change handler:

```
      FileUpload fileUpload=new FileUpload();
        fileUpload.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                if(isValidType()){ 
                     form.submit();
                 }
            }
        });
```

If you want more advanced uploading options, I would suggest look through [GWTUpload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) third party library.